# Does any of the material in Kobold Press' Sunken Empires clash mechanically with Alluria's Cerulean Seas?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I recently picked up *Cerulean Seas* (Alluria Publishing), and I'm loving it so far. I have previously purchased *Sunken Empires* (Kobold Press), and I'm not mechanics-savvy enough to recognise problems at a glance.

Are there any major problems with using these two books together?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what you mean by "clash." You will certainly have to make decisions in some cases as to which option you prefer.

**Characters**

Both products have both new content and adaptations of existing classes (Cerulean Seas a lot more than Sunken Empires).

For example, the Barbarian in CS has "All movement modifiers apply to swim speed.
For example, the Fast Movement ability applies to swim speed."

The SE barbarian has "Rapid Swimming (Ex): Starting at 2nd level, your natural
swim speed increases by +10 ft. This benefit applies only when
wearing no armor, light armor, or medium armor, and not when
carrying a heavy load. Apply this bonus before modifying the
speed because of any load carried or armor worn. This bonus
stacks with any other bonuses to swimming speed. This feature
replaces the fast movement ability." (Plus rage powers).

Whether you treat stuff like this as "conflicts" or "multiple options" is really more a matter of mindset.  I'd tell a barbarian's player "pick whichever you want!"

**Setting**

The two settings are very different and a lot of the options and gear and stuff are tied into the setting.  Again, you can see this as difference or just find a way to stitch one into the other. Though frankly, for a 290-page book that claims to be a "campaign setting, Cerulean Seas is really more of a crunch book with monsters and magic and stuff. So since both are light settings and SE focuses more on the remains of ancient undersea civilizations and CS focuses more on modern racial/political/religious division, merging both together - while it will still require work and thinking on your part to think through the logical relationships between the two (e.g. what happens if ixil have some vril weapons?) there should not really be "conflicts" per se, at least not for anyone who understands how to weave together multiple sources.